# Sitemesh different decorators for the same URL

Tags: spring, url-rewriting, struts2, sitemesh, appfuse

I'm using `urlrewriteFilter` (`org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter`) to forward pages like `www.mysite.com/myname` to a Struts2 action. The action is mapped up in sitemesh, and it works properly.

But now I want to keep the same URL but apply another decorator to the page, based on whether the user is logged in or not.

I'm using AppFuse-stack Struts2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - since no-one else looks like having a go.

Sitemesh selects the decorators based on the incoming url string, so to have different decorators you need different urls depending on the login status of your client. AFAIK Sitemesh uses the entire Url string so this includes parameters so you might get away with appending ?loggedIn="true" or ?loggedIn="false" and map the decorators on this. However this doesn't help with POST requests.

Another way to do it would be to create two Struts packages - one for logged in users and one for anonymous users so your actions will have different paths and then map on the path part of the Url.

I don't know how practical this might be in your scenario, but a third option maybe to have one common decorator and control the layout via seperate stylesheets which you could control via a  test in your jsp.

HTH
Regards